# Rewrite C++ bitshift operator in Python

Tags: python, c++, shift

I have this code in C++:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unsigned char v1;
    v1 = 23 << 6;
    cout << "v1: " << (int)v1;

    return 0;
}
```

When I execute it, it gives me result of 192.
But when I do the same (23 << 6) in Python I get 1472 instead of 192.
What am I doing wrong here? Do you know any method to rewrite this bitshift operation 1:1 to Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`23 << 6` is performed as an `int` in C++, but assigning it back to an `unsigned char` truncates it to its bits size (8 on any platform where Python runs). So, to obtain the same value in Python you have to do `(23 << 6) & 0xFF`.

On the other hand, to obtain the "correct" (non-truncated) result in C++ just assign it to an `unsigned int` instead of an `unsigned char` (this works if `int` is big enough for the result, otherwise you have to cast one operand to something bigger first; Python doesn't have such problems as it uses arbitrary size integers).

Comment: Oh yeah. Thank you very much. That was the thing I was looking for. :)